# Error installing Nvidia Drivers Fedora 35 Kernel 5.16.15

Tags: driver, nvidia, fedora

Spent three days trying to install nvidia graphic card drivers in Fedora 35 running on kernel 5.16. I was installing from the download .run file which threw error 'MIGRATE_PFN_LOCKED' undeclared in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/495.46/build/make.log

I tried installing without enabling dkms but still couldn't install the drivers

`systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

then

`systemctl reboot`

as root user. On logging in, change directory to where you download .run installer for your Nvidia graphic card and run below

`sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-XXX.XX.run --extract-only`

Above extract the installer file which will give us ability to edit the driver source code. Use your favorite editor to open the file uvm_migrate_pageable.c which is located in your extracted driver folder as below:

`kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm_migrate_pageable.c`

My favorite editor is vim, so in my case, I will open it for editing as below:-

`vim /NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-XXX.XX/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm_migrate_pageable.c`

Add below lines on declaration part of the source file or before where it is referenced in this c source file.

```
    #ifndef MIGRATE_PFN_LOCKED
    #define MIGRATE_PFN_LOCKED 0
    #endif
```

save the file and now run your driver as below while inside the folder we extracted:

`./nvidia-installer`

Installation process should now complete without any errors and you can now revert to your X windowing system by running the command:

`systemctl set-default desktop.target`

References:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=271400

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ab09243aa95a72bac5c71e852773de34116f8d0f

Answer (score 0):

Issue: The NVIDIA team do not yet have support for kernel 5.16.15 for the time being.

Solution: Patch the current installer yourself by running below, note that you must have x disabled probably by logging into your fedora via text mode which can be achieved by running the command